# Verificar se registro existe na tabela e retornar no mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, select, sql-select

Olá tenho uma tabela chamada logs

```
id | usuario_id | produto_id
1  |     10     |   20
2  |     10     |   30
3  |     20     |   30
4  |     20     |   20
```

São logs informando que o usuario com id 10 já viu o produto com id 20, e o mesmo usuario com id 10 viu o produto 30.

Já fiz uma ação que quando ele clica no botão visualizar insere na tabela logs o id do usuário e id do produto.

Queria fazer a seguinte situação.
Na lista do produto
onde tem o `id | nome | preço`
Ele fica em negrito, se o usuário não visualizou, e se já visualizou fica normal.

```
<tr style="
<?php
$user = $_SESSION['usuarioId']; //pega a sessão do usuário logado
$sql = "SELECT * FROM logs WHERE usuario_id = '{$user}'"; //monto a query
$row = $sql->fetch_row();
if ($row[0] > 0) {//se retornar algum resultado
echo 'font-weight: 700;';
} else {
echo 'font-weight: 300;';
}
?>">
```

A ideia é se o usuário da sessão não estiver na tabela daquele produto, ele fica font 700, se ele estiver fica font 300.

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Para verificar se a `row` existe apenas faça isto:**

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM logs WHERE usuario_id = '{$user}'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    echo 'font-weight: 300;';
} else {
    echo 'font-weight: 700;';
}
```

Comment: não funcionou. Ele está retornando sempre o primeiro IF.

Comment: Então é porque a row existe

Comment: Resolvido assim:`<?php 
          $userid = $row_usuario["id"];
       $result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM logs WHERE usuario_id = '{$userid}'");
       $row = $result->fetch_row();
       if ($row[0] > 0){
          echo "font-weight:300;";
       }
          else { 
          echo "font-weight:700;";<br>
       }
       ?>`

Answer (score -4):

Eu apenas fiz:

```
if($rows["product_id"]){
     echo '**EXISTE**';
}else{
     echo '**NÃO EXISTE**';
}
```